# If I deploy google app script, is there any chance of being searched in google search?

Tags: google-apps-script

I just deployed my app script(web app) and I got my Url (https://script.google.com/macros/s/blahblah.../exec).

( setting [Who has access to the app: ] -> [Anyone] )

So I worried about that my Url can be known for anyone in the google search.
I want to use this link only with my friends.

Is it safe unless I don't share the Url to others? (except my friends)
or is there anyway to force to request permission to my web app? (without using G suite, google Workspace)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Your Web App is not indexed by Google

Unless you share your project URL with other people, they can't directly access to it.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions) the app can be executed as you or as the user accessing the web app. You can limit the access to your resources by changing the user who's executing your app.